# I need to plot unsorted values MPAndroidChart Line Chart

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

I am building an app to plot data, similar to a roadmap.  The X & Y  values are not necessarily in ascending order, sometimes the road loops back.  I need the graph to get the data from a database.  There is an error everytime the values decrease. I'm not sure how to plot this or bypass the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

The [library documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data#the-order-of-entries) warns about this.

> Please be aware that this library does not officially support drawing
>   LineChart data from an Entry list not sorted by the x-position of the
>   entries in ascending manner. Adding entries in an unsorted way may
>   result in correct drawing, but may also lead to unexpected behaviour.
>   A List of Entry objects can be sorted manually or using the
>   EntryXComparator:
>
> ```
> List<Entry> entries = ...;
> Collections.sort(entries, new EntryXComparator());
> ```
>
> The reason why this is required is because the library uses binary
>   search algorithms for better performance only working on sorted lists.